# Custom Keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

It sounds like a very simple question but I couldn't find that much info.

If I create my own keyboard (number pad keyboard), how can I set that as my keyboard in Android?

This keyboard will only be used for one or two `EditText` fields.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.pinyinjoe.com/other-os/android-ime-switching-and-settings.htm

Comment: That is if you want to change the default keyboard.  That is system settings.  I don't want to do that.  In iOS for example, if I want to use my own keyboard, all I have to do is this:  `myTextField.InputView = myCustomKeyboard;`.  I am looking for something similar

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Comment: thanks for that link.  that link also led to me the following post:  http://goo.gl/F7r3fl  but they both require user to change the input setting in system settings.  I only want this keyboard for ONE textfield in my app.  It doesn't seem convenient to ask user to change it for one textfield.

Comment: Use a virtual keyboard. View with buttons to do your job.